# SQL Conditional Query

Tags: sql

I have an SQL query that I am trying that I am sure is easy, but I am not that well versed so I can't quite figure it out. Wasn't even sure how to word the question. Anyway here is what I am looking at:

I have a table that has the following columns: Hostname, Path, Filename, Filesize

It is essentially a directory listing of a number of computers (Hostnames).

What I want to get is a list of distinct Hostnames where neither of two paths exist for that host. For example, grab all Hostnames that do not have a corresponding C:\users\Jeff or C:\users\Mary directory. If they have one of the two, omit. Only return them if neither of these directories exist.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Please show what you've tried, we're not here to do your homework for you. You have to make an attempt, then we'll show you where you went wrong, and that's how you learn.

Comment: Also, please add a tag for the RDBMS you're using. Different databases provide different ways to do this kind of query.

Comment: Even if you have troubles with the SQL statement, show us the table architecture already. That is something we're all used to see, and I think it's more visible then. Now all the queries posted have all kind of different naming of columns and table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend splitting this into two parts:

1. Generate the list of all host names.
2. Generate the list of all host names that contain a path you don't want.

Then, use `MINUS` (which automatically removes duplicates) to get the unique results:

```
SELECT hostname
FROM table
MINUS
SELECT hostname
FROM table
WHERE path IN ('/search/path/one', '/search/path/two')
```

You can also use an anti-join instead of a `MINUS`, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Excellent. I can see the use of MINUS being very useful. Didn't know it existed (as I said, very new to SQL) - Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `MINUS`/`EXCEPT` remove duplicates so the `DISTINCT`s are not needed.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Good point.  The second `DISTINCT` isn't required.  If the hostname appears multiple times in the second query, it will still only be removed once.

Comment: Neither are required. MINUS (like `UNION`) doesn't return duplicates,

Comment: @MartinSmith - Huh, today I learned.  I thought `MINUS` and `UNION` suppressed duplicates *between* the two inputs, I didn't realize it deduped the inputs themselves.

Answer (score 4):

One way

```
SELECT HostName
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY HostName
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Path IN ('C:\users\Jeff',
                                'C:\users\Mary') THEN 1 END) =0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct hostname from your_table t1
where not exists (select 1 from your_table t2 
                  where t2.hostname = t1.hostname 
                    and t2.path in ('C:\users\Jeff', 'C:\users\Mary'));
```